# Change node machine type on GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE cluster I'm trying to switch the default node machine type on.

I have already tried:

1. Creating a new node pool with the machine type I want
2. Deleting the default-pool. GKE will process for a bit, then not remove the default-pool. I assume this is some undocumented behavior where you cannot delete the default-pool.

I'd prefer to not re-create the cluster and re-apply all of my deployments/secrets/configs/etc.

k8s version: `1.14.10-gke.24` (Stable channel)

Cluster Type: Regional

Answer (score 15):

The best approach to change/increase/decrease your `node pool` specification would be with:

- **Migration**

To migrate your workloads without incurring downtime, you need to:

- Create a new `node pool`.
- Mark the existing `node pool` as unschedulable.
- Drain the workloads running on the existing `node pool`.
- **Check if the workload is running correctly on a new `node pool`.**
- Delete the existing `node pool`.

Your workload will be scheduled automatically onto a new `node pool`.

> [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/), which is the cluster orchestration system of GKE clusters, automatically reschedules the evicted [Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/) to the new node pool as it drains the existing node pool.

There is official documentation about migrating your workload:

> This tutorial demonstrates how to migrate workloads running on a GKE cluster to a new set of nodes within the same cluster without incurring downtime for your application. Such a migration can be useful if you want to migrate your workloads to nodes with a different machine type.
>
> -- *[GKE: Migrating workloads to different machine types](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool)*

Please take a look at above guide and let me know if you have any questions in that topic.

Comment: Hey Dawid, the above works fine for a standard k8s node pool workload migration, but does not account for the default-pool GKE provides which cannot be deleted.

Comment: The default `node pool` can be deleted. I tested it myself. You need to check what is blocking your default `node pool` deletion.

Comment: Huh, will have to give that another try then. Is there a place in GCP where I can see what is blocking the deletion?

Comment: @Jacque006 which method of deletion of a `node-pool` did you try? `gcloud` or web version? Please try to follow this link: [Node pools](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-pools) section of "Deleting a node pool". You can check the status of this operation on the top right corner with a bell icon.

Comment: Web. Status showed it was deleted, but then got a message saying my cluster was recovering and it popped back up.

Comment: @Jacque006 please if it's possible post an exact message that you got when deleting this `node pool`.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the default-pool's autoscaler and set the pool size to 0 nodes.

Wish there was a way I could just switch the machine type on the default-pool...

Comment: On another note, it looks like using the f1-micro machine type with StackDriver enabled leaves you with ~10 MB of requestable memory per node. Not even sure why that machine type is allowed. Maybe I should send GCP some RasberryPIs they can plug into my cluster :)

Comment: You need at least 3 nodes (GKE requirement). However I can confirm that once your second node pool is up, with at least 3 nodes, you can indeed set the number of nodes in the default pool to zero.